# dmesg flooded with "ataXX.00: failed to IDENTIFY" for mystery drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hardware, ubuntu-20.04

My `dmesg` is flooded with the following every ~second (note, the following repeat forever; but the exact sequence appears to vary):

```
ata15.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
ata15: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
ata15: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 310)
ata15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
ata15.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x100)
```

I see PCI ID from

```
# ls -l /sys/class/ata_port/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 10 11:08 ata15 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:09.0/0000:08:00.0/ata15/ata_port/ata15
```

It appears (I'm not 100% on the output format of `lspci`) that the relevant PCI id/port here is `08`; but there is no corresponding entry in `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path`

```
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-path
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:01:00.0-nvme-1 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:01:00.0-nvme-1-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:01:00.0-nvme-1-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:01:00.0-nvme-1-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:01:00.0-nvme-1-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:04:00.0-ata-1 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:04:00.0-ata-2 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-1 -> ../../sr1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-2 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-2-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-5 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-5-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-6 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec  7 11:30 pci-0000:09:00.0-ata-6-part1 -> ../../sde1
```

I believe the relevant device from `lspci -nn` is

```
08:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

Is there a way to glean any more information about what device is attached here?  I don't have easy physical access to the machine to trial-and-error.  (FWIW, The only hypothesis I could offer is this is a DVDR drive that the server has installed for manual hard backups.)

Comment: No, because it `failed to IDENTIFY`. Next step is to open the server and physically inspect it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton- so you're saying `IDENTIFY` is the first command(?) sent?  Is this a PCI/pcie command, or sata?